# Need help properly formatting try-except statements with python

Tags: python, try-except

Following a tutorial (just starting to learn) and I seem to be following the code perfectly but the result is not printing properly.

Here is my code:

```
num1 = 8

num2 = int(input("Input a number: "))

try:
    result = num1/num2
    print(result)
except ZeroDivisionError:
    print("do not divide by zero")
except TypeError:
    print("your input value must be an integer")

print("The program keeps executing to do other stuff")
```

Inputting "0" does print the correct error. However, when inputting a string I am expecting

```
"Your input value must be an integer.
The program keeps executing to do other stuff..."
```

Instead I get:

```
File "c:\Users\kevin\Python\troubleshoot.py", line 3, in <module>
    num2 = int(input("Input a number: "))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'the'
```

I have tried changing the line 3 a few ways as it seems that is the issue but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to convert a string to an int, and it doesn't like that?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are getting your first exception at the point in your code where you are attempting to convert the user input from a string to an integer.  A string that cannot be converted into an integer will generate a `ValueError`, so you need to deal with that before checking for a `ZeroDivisionError`:

```
num1 = 8

try:
    num2 = int(input("Input a number: "))
except ValueError as exc:
    print("your input value must be an integer")
else:
    try:
        result = num1/num2
        print(result)
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("do not divide by zero")

print("The program keeps executing to do other stuff")
```

Comment: This worked awesome thank you! I actually did try to change my TypeError to a ValueError but did not rearrange the order. This makes sense thank you so much again. I'm learning to not blindly follow tutorials.